# Check whether these 2 SQLs are same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to optimize my SQL. I have made some changes. Not sure these changes are correect or not,

Is this SQL,

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOldDeviceID]
            (
                @OldDeviceID VARCHAR(500)
                ,@NewDeviceID  VARCHAR(500)
            )
            AS
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                DECLARE @TranCount INT;
                SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

                BEGIN TRY
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        BEGIN TRANSACTION
                    ELSE
                        SAVE TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

                    IF @NewDeviceID <> '-1' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @NewDeviceID) 
                    BEGIN 
                        INSERT INTO [DeviceCatalog]
                                    ([os]
                                    ,[uniqueid]
                                    ,[address]
                                    ,[location]
                                    ,[culture]
                                    ,[city]
                                    ,[country]
                                    ,[other]
                                    ,[lastmodifieddate]
                                    ,[createddate]
                                    ,[IsActive]
                                    ,[IPAddress]
                                    ,[NativeDeviceID]
                                    ,[IsDeleted])
                            SELECT  [os]
                                    ,@NewDeviceID
                                    ,[address]
                                    ,[location]
                                    ,[culture]
                                    ,[city]
                                    ,[country]
                                    ,[other]
                                    ,GETDATE()
                                    ,GETDATE()
                                    ,[IsActive]
                                    ,[IPAddress]
                                    ,[NativeDeviceID]
                                    ,[IsDeleted]
                            FROM    [DeviceCatalog]
                            WHERE   [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID;
                    END
                    DELETE FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID; -- Always Delete old one
            LBEXIT:
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        COMMIT;
                    END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
                    SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

                    IF @XState = -1
                        ROLLBACK;
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
                        rollback
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

                    RAISERROR ('DeleteOldDeviceID: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
                END CATCH
            END
```

is equal to this,

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOldDeviceID]
            (
                @OldDeviceID VARCHAR(500)
                ,@NewDeviceID  VARCHAR(500)
            )
            AS
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                DECLARE @TranCount INT;
                SET @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT;

                BEGIN TRY
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        BEGIN TRANSACTION
                    ELSE
                        SAVE TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

                    IF @NewDeviceID <> '-1' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @NewDeviceID) 
                    BEGIN   
                            UPDATE  [DeviceCatalog]
                               SET  [UniqueID] = @NewDeviceID
                            WHERE   [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID;
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        DELETE FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE [UniqueID] = @OldDeviceID; -- Always Delete old one
                    END
        LBEXIT:
                    IF @TranCount = 0
                        COMMIT;
                    END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    DECLARE @Error INT, @Message VARCHAR(4000), @XState INT;
                    SELECT  @Error = ERROR_NUMBER() ,@Message = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,@XState = XACT_STATE();

                    IF @XState = -1
                        ROLLBACK;
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount = 0
                        rollback
                    IF @XState = 1 AND @TranCount > 0
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DeleteOldDeviceID;

                    RAISERROR ('DeleteOldDeviceID: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
                END CATCH
            END
```

Comment: Well, do they return the same results? You are in a much better position to determine whether the new version behaves the same as the old version. You have the code *and* the data. All we have is the code. This is a task you should perform yourself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, OK Thanks. I will check. I like your blog a lot